# How can I filter youtube videos by category id 10 i.e. Music?

Tags: php, video, youtube

Below is the URL I am using to search **YouTube** Videos:

```
 // One Url
$youtube_api_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?
                       part=snippet&id=10&key=".GOOGLE_API_KEY;

 // Two Url
 $youtube_api_url = $youtube_api_url."&regionCode=GB&playlistId=
                       ".$playlist_id."&order=relevance&maxResults=50&
                 part=snippet&q=".urlencode($artist->name.' Music Video Vevo');
```

I have separate link as :

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&id=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](http://%20https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&id=10&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)

To know category id. But how can I filter fetched videos by category id.

Comment: Put youtube a side for a moment, do you know how to filter data in general? Show the results of the code we dont know whether the ID comes back as an array or an object therefore we cannot help

Comment: response doesn't return video categories rather it provides different url that returns all categories available in youtube

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint. Indeed by fetching https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=VIDEO_ID&key=API_KEY you'll retrieve whether or not the category id of the video is `10` in [`items[0]/snippet/categoryId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.categoryId).

Furthermore note that your second assignment to `$youtube_api_url` looks incorrect (depending on what you do with this variable), as it contains two URLs.